# Why does SQL Server gives a login error when I try to import data-tier application, even though the target database was recently deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms

I'm trying to copy the contents of one database `DB` to another database `DB_DEV` on SQL Server Management Studio. I'm doing this by deleting `DB_DEV`, exporting a data-tier application from `DB`, and then importing it back to `DB_DEV`. This has worked for some other databases, but for this particular one, I am getting an error when I try to import the database:

[image]

This occurs immediately after I press next on the Database Settings page.

This is really weird because the database is not supposed to exist in the first place, since it's been recently deleted. The account I'm using should be able to create new databases. It logs in elsewhere just fine.

Other things of note:

- I know this isn't a problem with the BACPAC file because I can import it to other databases with different names without issues.
- I can right click and create a new database with the name `DB_DEV` just fine. I just can't import to it.
- It seems like other people with this error are doing something related to IIS. I don't see similar errors when people are only interacting with SSMS.

SQL Server is version 12.0.2000.8.

Anybody got any ideas? Would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you *really* running SQL Server 12.0.2000.8? That's SQL Server 2014 RTM! Why haven't you updated your version in 7 years!

Comment: Update if anyone cares: I just had to wait a few days and it fixed itself, lol.

Comment: Did you apply the last 7 years of updates while you were there too?

Comment: Hi @EvanZheng, no matter which SQL Server version you are using, glad to hear it fixed itself. I just help you post it answer to end this question. you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed itself. I help post it an answer to end this question:

- "Update if anyone cares: I just had to wait a few days and it fixed
  itself."